# format json.net date using jQuery

Tags: jquery, datepicker, json.net

I have got the following dates (shown using HTML) from JSON.NET.

```
<span class="date"> 2013-01-01T00:00:00  </span>
<span class="date"> 2009-05-01T00:00:00  </span>
<span class="date"> 2011-01-06T00:00:00  </span>
<span class="date"> 2012-03-09T00:00:00  </span>
```

How can I covenrt these dates to the format 'mm-dd-yyyy'. That means, the HTML should be like this:

```
<span class="date"> 01-01-2013  </span>
<span class="date"> 05-01-2009  </span>
<span class="date"> 01-06-2011  </span>
<span class="date"> 03-09-2012  </span>
```

I tried several ways using jQuery DatePicker and DateFormat. I also got similar questions on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215508/how-to-format-this-date-type-2010-06-24t000000z-to-sun-24-06-10-7-15-p-m-cdt). But still I coudn't figure this out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI `datepicker.parseDate` can't parse times, so you'll have to remove them:

```
var input = "2013-01-01T00:00:00";
input = input.split("T")[0]; // "2013-01-01"
var date = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", input);
```

Then using `formatDate` shouldn't be a problem:

```
var newDateString = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm-dd-yy", date);
```

To get the span html:

```
var spanHtml = "<span class='date'> " + newDateString + " </span>";
```

Comment: How can I get this output `<span class="date"> 01-01-2013  </span>` after using formatDate?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span').text(function(i, v){
   var d = new Date($.trim(v));
   return (d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + d.getDate() + '-' + d.getFullYear();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BdMfp/

Comment: It cannot convert correctly. E.g. the date'2014-01-01T00:00:00' converts to 12-31-2013.

Comment: I tested it using my ASP.NET website and using your [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BdMfp/). Both websites show earlier dates. I am running Chrome on XP.